# Implement the `From` trait from an associated type

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I'm writing an Error `enum` that represents failure to parse a value obtained from a program's arguments. Initially, it looks like this:

```rust
pub enum LoadingError {
    NoArg,
    CantParse
}
```

I'd like it to be easily converted from a parsing error. The `str::parse` function is defined as follows:

```rust
pub fn parse<F: FromStr>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err> {
    FromStr::from_str(self)
}
```

It seems to me that, if I want to implement the `From` trait for my `enum` converting from any `FromStr::Err`, I would need my function to be generic on the `FromStr` trait. I tried doing something like this:

```rust
pub enum LoadingError<F: FromStr> {
    NoArg,
    CantParse(F::Err)
}

impl<F: FromStr> From<F::Err> for LoadingError<F> {
    fn from(err: F::Err) -> LoadingError<F> {
        LoadingError::CantParse(err)
    }
}
```

This, however, does not compile, with this error being returned:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<LoadingError<_>>` for type `LoadingError<_>`
  --> src/main.rs:15:1
   |
15 | impl<F: FromStr> From<F::Err> for LoadingError<F> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

I don't really see how implementations with these two different type signatures would be conflicting, and I couldn't find the definition for `impl<T> From<T> for T` in Rust's core code.

I've also tried using the `thiserror` crate, leading me to the same error.

```rust
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum LoadingError<F: FromStr> {
    #[error("can't find argument")]
    NoArg,
    #[error("couldn't parse")]
    CantParse(#[from] F::Err)
}
```

My question is: How can I implement the `From` trait for my type from any of the many `Err`s defined by the `FromStr` trait?

Comment: *"I couldn't find the definition for ..."* - https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-for-T

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Why would you want that ? I recommend you don't use `FromStr::Err` just put the concrete error type in your error enum, forget about this generic in your enum, it's out of place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `impl<T> From<T> for T` is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-for-T).

Second, any type can be `FromStr::Err`, including `LoadingError`. If it was possible to make an impl that only worked on types that were used in `FromStr::Err`, then it would be possible to change the meaning of your code from outside your crate by writing a `FromStr` impl that uses an error type that you assumed wasn't used in `FromStr::Err`.

Instead, you should create `From` impls on the actual error types you're looking for, like [`ParseIntError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.ParseIntError.html).

```rs
pub enum LoadingError<F> {
    NoArg,
    CantParse(F)
}

use std::num::ParseIntError;
impl From<ParseIntError> for LoadingError<ParseIntError> {
    fn from(value: ParseIntError) -> Self {
        LoadingError::CantParse(value)
    }
}
```

Or you can create a method to convert any error into `LoadingError` and only use it on the result of `parse`.

```rs
impl<F> LoadingError<F> {
    pub fn convert_parse<T>(result: Result<T, F>) -> Result<T, Self> {
        result.map_err(|e| LoadingError::CantParse(e))
    }
}
```

You can use this like:

```rs
LoadingError::convert_parse("1".parse::<i32>())
```

Using a generic on your error type can be problematic, so you may want to store a trait object instead (or use a trait object as the generic).

```rs
use std::error::Error;

pub enum LoadingError {
    NoArg,
    CantParse(Box<dyn Error>)
}

use std::num::ParseIntError;
impl From<ParseIntError> for LoadingError {
    fn from(value: ParseIntError) -> Self {
        LoadingError::CantParse(Box::new(value))
    }
}

impl LoadingError {
    pub fn convert_parse<T, F: Error + 'static>(result: Result<T, F>) -> Result<T, Self> {
        result.map_err(|e| LoadingError::CantParse(Box::new(e)))
    }
}
```